# Best way to store a list in Django (Not Postgres)

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a mysql database and am storing a list. Im currently storing it as a CharField but dont know if this is the best way to do it. I know that I should be using an ArrayFeild if my db was postgres, but its MYSQL.

I was content with this solution till I realized that the data was being stored like this:`['COM', 'CRI', 'CUL', 'FOO']` whereas id expect it to be stored like this:`[['COM'], ['CRI'], ['CUL'], ['FOO']]`.

forms.py

```
TOPICS = (
        ('ANI', 'Animals'),
        ('ART', 'Art'),
        ('COM', 'Communication'),
    )

    topics = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TOPICS, required=False, 
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

models.py

```
topics = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

How the data is stored in my db:

```
['COM', 'CRI', 'CUL', 'FOO']
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah thats a bit tricky. I had the same issue. I tried to do it with stuff like toString etc.
I ended up in using a JSONField. So u can throw everything into a var and when u save this Django converts this to a JSONField in DB. If u load it from ur Database u can access the Values like always. U can loop it or whatever u want to do with it

In models.py

```
import jsonfield

class Example(models.Model):
   example = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

So this works fine for me, if u need anything else let me know. 
pip install django-jsonfield 
The pip command.

If u need some more Examples or a Code Example let me know.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will give that a try tomorrow and let you know how I go. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Let the Django store it like this, you can later manipulate the list to convert it into the list of lists like:

```
>>>lst = ['COM', 'CRI', 'CUL', 'FOO']
>>>[[i] for i in lst]
[['COM'], ['CRI'], ['CUL'], ['FOO']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Tomorrow I will give sheep64's answer a go and if it doesnt work il do this :)